# Обращение к определенному тегу xml

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

Имеется xml с множеством элементов. Некоторые элементы имеют одинаковое название но дочерние элементы могу отличаться.
Структура xml примерно следующая:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>data1</tag2>
  <tag3>data2</tag3>
  <tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag6>value1</tag6>
      <tag7>value2</tag7>
      <tag8>value3</tag8>
      <tag9>value4</tag9>
      <tag10>value5</tag10>
    </tag5>
    <tag5>
      <tag6>value6</tag6>
      <tag7>value7</tag7>
      <tag8>value8</tag8>
      <tag9>value9</tag9>
      <tag10>value10</tag10>
    </tag5>
  </tag4>
</tag1>
```

Необходимо получить значение tag9 если tag10 удовлетворяет определенному условию

Код java:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new File("someXML.xml"));

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList tagFiveNodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("tag5");

    for (int i = 0; i < tagFiveNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node tagFiveNode = tagFiveNodeList.item(i);
        NodeList tagFiveChildNodes = tagFiveNode.getChildNodes();

        for (int j = 0; j < tagFiveChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Node tagFiveChildNode = tagFiveChildNodes.item(j);
            // проверка условия
            if (tagFiveChildNode.getTextContent().contains("Some Text")) {

            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

После проверки на содержание в любом из дочерних тегов определенного текста я хочу получить значение другого тега из этого же списка дочерних тегов.
 Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить приведение `Node` к `Element`

```
Element tagFiveNode = (Element)tagFiveNodeList.item(i);
```

А потом использовать метод `getElementsByTagName`

```
if (tagFiveNode.getElementsByTagName('tag10').item(0).getTextContent()....)
  value = tagFiveNode.getElementsByTagName('tag9').item(0).getTextContent();
```

Это при условии, что такие узлы существуют. Если они могут отсутствовать, то нужно еще проверить размер коллекции, возвращаемой методом `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Всё дело в чтом, tagFiveNode является Node, а у Node, как и у NodeList нет метода getElementsByTagName.

Comment: @SlavaNear Выполните приведение `Element tagFiveNode = (Element)tagFiveNodeList.item(i);`

Comment: Благодарю. Всё работает